# Vesta CP Downgrade PHP version to 5.2.17 (CentOS 64bit)

Tags: vesta

Help Me! Help Me! Vesta version of the installation in the default PHP is 5.6, but the environment is php5.2.17 program requirements and installation is ZendOptimizer - 3.3.9
Is there a way to downgrade to php5.2.17, mount ZendOptimizer - 3.3.9 again at the same time.

Comment: Don't. PHP 5.2 reached end-of-life almost six years ago. You need to get with the times and figure out whatever problem is keeping your site from working on PHP 5.6 or later. ([PHP 5.4 reached end-of-life over a year ago too](http://php.net/eol.php), so it's not a good idea to use either.)

Comment: Can't, I use the program is the zend encrypted, installation must be such conditions and requirements

Comment: That means the program is at least 6 years old, and probably even older -- it's probably insecure. Get an updated copy from the vendor, or use something else.

Comment: I don't know why the supplier to do so anyway, their development environment is php5.2.17 ZendOptimizer - 3.3.9, I just want to learn, so just want to make a such an environment.